# back button should not be activated when logout button is clicked in java servlet and not in jsp

Tags: java, servlets

i want to secure the home page after the logout button is pressed. But the code of mine is not working. Help me to get the code work.

```
public class logout extends HttpServlet {  
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
                    throws ServletException, IOException {  
    response.setContentType("text/html");  
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();          



out.print("you are successfully logged out!");  
out.println("<br/><a href=\"login.html\">Login</a>");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); 


out.close();

}  
}
```

Comment: I think, you should use `response.sendRedirect("location")`.

Comment: sorry, i dint get you, where to use above statement @AmidalaSivaKumar

Comment: Refer the below docs https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)